# CSS Not working on HTML

Tags: html, css

I have the html file i created. However the CSS properties are not showing the i view it in the browser. Am not sure where am getting it wrong.

As Opposed to using a separate file file the CSS , I have included it in the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>List of processed transations</title>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html  charset=UTF-16">
<style>
.attr-col { margin: 110px 0 0  float: left  width: 200px  }
.attr-col ul { background: #f4f4f4  font-weight: bold  font-size: 13px  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px  border-top-left-radius: 5px  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px  }
.attr-col { margin: 110px 0 0  float: left  width: 200px  }
.attr-col ul li { text-align: right  padding: 0 10px  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6  line-height: 45px  display: block  }
.attr-col ul li.last { border-bottom: none  }
.pt-table { padding-left: 200px  display: block  position: relative  }
.pt-body { padding: 10px 0 0  }
.pt-rows li { display: block  overflow: hidden background: #fff  border-left: 2px solid #ccc  border-right: 2px solid #ccc  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9   }
.pt-rows li span { width: 24%  text-align: center  float: left  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9  display: block  line-height: 45px  height: 45px  }
.pt-rows li.title { background: #666  font-size: 22px  color: #fff  font-weight: bold  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px  border-top-left-radius: 5px  border-bottom: 2px solid #555  border-width: 0 0 2px  }
.pt-rows li.title span { text-align:center  line-height: 50px  height: 50px  border: none  padding: 0 1px  text-shadow: 2px 2px #444  }
.pt-rows li.Record_Type { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc  }
.pt-rows li.Record_Type span { line-height: 48px  height: 48px  background: #f7f7f7  font-size: 22px  font-weight: 700  font-family: Georgia, Arial, sans-serif  color: #4172a5  text-shadow: 2px 2px #fff  }
.pt-rows li.fin { border-bottom: 2px solid #d9d9d9  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px  height: 85px  }
.pt-rows li span.pt-3x { width: 72%  float: left  text-align: center  border: none  }
.pt-table1 { padding-left:0px  display: block  position: relative  }
.pt-body1 { padding: 0px 0 0  }
.pt-rows1 li { display: block  overflow: hidden  background: #fff  border-left: 2px solid #ccc  border-right: 2px solid #ccc  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9   }
.pt-rows1 li span { width: 20%  text-align: center  float: left  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9  display: auto  line-height: 45px  height: 45px  }
.pt-rows1 li.title1 { background: #666  font-size: 22px  color: #fff  font-weight: bold  }
.pt-rows1 li.title1 span { text-align:center  height: 50px  border: none  padding: 0 0px  text-shadow: 4px 4px #444  }
.pt-rows1 li.Record_Type1 { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc  }
.pt-rows1 li.Record_Type1 span { line-height: 22px  height: 22px  background: #f7f7f7  font-size: 12px  font-weight: 700  font-family: Georgia, Arial, sans-serif  color: #4172a5  text-shadow: 2px 2px #fff  }
.pt-rows1 li span.pt-3x { width: 20%  float: left  text-align: left  border: none  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<br><h3>Incoming File Transactions For File EON1001D_20150613</h3>
<div class="eft-extract">
<div class="pt-table">
<div class="pt-body">
<ul class="pt-rows">
<li class="title"><span></span></li>
<li class="Record_Type"><span>Record ID:</span><span>Count</span><span>Amount</span></li>
<li><span>10</span><span>      21</span><span>42990.83</span></li><li><span>Total</span><span>21</span><span>42990.83</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br><h3>Contracts Generated Generated For File EON1001D_20150613</h3>
<div class="eft-extract">
<div class="pt-table">
<div class="pt-body">
<ul class="pt-rows">
<li class="title"><span></span></li>
<li class="Record_Type"><span>Contract Type:</span><span>Count</span><span>Amount</span></li>
<li><span>ITPT</span><span>20</span><span>42847.16</span></li><li><span>Total</span><span>20</span><span>42847.16</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br><h3>Differences For File EON1001D_20150613</h3>
<div class="eft-extract">
<div class="pt-table">
<div class="pt-body">
<ul class="pt-rows">
<li class="title"><span></span></li>
<li class="Record_Type"><span>::</span><span>Count:</span><span>Amount:</span></li>
<li><span>.</span><span>1</span><span>143.67</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br><h3>Failed Contracts  For File EON1001D_20150613</h3>
<div class="eft-extract">
<div class="pt-table">
<div class="pt-body">
<ul class="pt-rows">
<li class="title"><span></span></li>
<li class="Record_Type"><span>PC Contract Reference::</span><span>Reject Code:</span><span>Reject Reason:</span></li>
<li><span></span><span></span><span></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br><h3>Transactions On File Not Processed For File EON1001D_20150613</h3>
<div class="eft-extract">
<div class="pt-table">
<div class="pt-body">
<ul class="pt-rows">
<li class="title"><span></span></li>
<li class="Record_Type"><span>Serial Number:</span>
<span>Nominated Account:</span>
<span>Amount:</span>
<span>User Ref:</span>

<li><span>5</span><span>1960000292</span><span>143.67</span><span>AMWAY</span></li><li><span>    </span><span></span><span></span><span></span></li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS syntax isn't correct, you missed semicolons between properties. It couldn't work nor as external stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

That is, because your CSS syntax is wrong. 
Each and every declaration must end with a semicolon.

example:

```
.pt-table { padding-left: 200px  display: block  position: relative  }
```

must become:

```
pt-table { padding-left: 200px;  display: block;  position: relative;  }
```

See e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: After adding the semicolon am still getting the same results

Comment: @NicholasNamacha You also need to either add another semicolon between "text/html" and "charset=UTF-16" like so content="text/html;  charset=UTF-16"> or (better) use the appropriate HTML5 definition (because you use the html5 doctype too) see: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations and http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp